# Removing cells from Voronoi mesh if they exceed a certain area or circumference

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

I start with the example in [Finding the perimeter, area and number of sides of a Voronoi cell](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20646/finding-the-perimeter-area-and-number-of-sides-of-a-voronoi-cell/57135#57135) with [RunnyKine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5709/runnykine)'s answer:

```
pts = RandomReal[4, {20, 2}];
vor = VoronoiMesh[pts, {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}]; (* bounded Voronoi diagram *)
HighlightMesh[vor, {Style[2, White], Style[1, Thick, Red], Labeled[2, "Index"]}]
```

[image]

**How can I *remove* cells which exceed a certain threshold of area or circumference?**

I do not want to display such cells and also not consider them when calculation the mean area, mean circumference or when showing corresponding histograms for vortices, area, and circumference.

In the upper plot: is it possible e.g. to show how to remove from `vor` the smallest cell concerning area (probably number 5) and the largest concerning area (probably number 17).

RunnyKine showed in his answer how to determine the cell areas:

```
cells = MeshCells[vor, 2]; (* The polygons that make up the Voronoi diagram *) 
cellcoord = Map[MeshCoordinates[vor][[#]] &, cells, {2}];
areas = Area /@ cellcoord;
```

And also he measured the perimeters:

```
RegionMeasure /@ (MeshPrimitives[vor, 2] /. Polygon[{x_, y__}] :> Line[{x, y, x}])
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So this would create a mesh region where we've removed all the cells whose area is larger than the average area,

```
pts = RandomReal[4, {20, 2}];
vor = VoronoiMesh[
  pts, {{0, 4}, {0, 
    4}}];
HighlightMesh[vor, {Style[2, 
   White], Style[1, Thick, Red], Labeled[2, "Index"]}]
vor2 = Show[
    Graphics /@ 
     Select[MeshPrimitives[vor, 2], 
      Area[#] < Mean[PropertyValue[{vor, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]] &]] // 
   DiscretizeGraphics;
HighlightMesh[vor2, {Style[2, White], Style[1, Thick, Red], 
  Labeled[2, "Index"]}]
```

[image]

If it is necessary that the new cells have the same index number, that would be a bit trickier I think.

For the perimeter, it's convenient to define an auxilliary function,

```
polygonPerimeter[Polygon[{x_, y__}]] := RegionMeasure[Line[{x, y, x}]];

vor2 = Show[
    Graphics /@ 
     Select[MeshPrimitives[vor, 2], 
      polygonPerimeter[#] < 
        Mean[polygonPerimeter /@ MeshPrimitives[vor, 2]] &]] // 
   DiscretizeGraphics;
HighlightMesh[vor2, {Style[2, White], Style[1, Thick, Red], 
  Labeled[2, "Index"]}]
```

[image]

You could show the different cells together, highlighting based on whether they are smaller or larger than the mean,

```
pts = RandomReal[4, {20, 2}];
vor = VoronoiMesh[pts, {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}];
vor12 = DiscretizeGraphics[Show[Graphics /@ #]] & /@ 
   GatherBy[MeshPrimitives[vor, 2], 
    Area[#] > Mean[PropertyValue[{vor, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]] &];
Show[
 HighlightMesh[vor12[[1]], {Style[2, Blue], Style[1, Thick, Black]}],
 HighlightMesh[vor12[[2]], {Style[2, Red], Style[1, Thick, Black]}]
 ]
```

And finally, if you wanted to keep only the four-sided regions,

```
vor2 = Show[
    Graphics /@ 
     Select[MeshPrimitives[vor, 2], 
      Length[First[List @@ #]] == 4 &]] // DiscretizeGraphics;
HighlightMesh[vor2, {Style[2, White], Style[1, Thick, Red], 
  Labeled[2, "Index"]}]
```

[image]

Comment: No, the index ist not important ... that is great what you did. For the circumference: could you propose how to select in this case the cells (e.g. if they are below the mean circumference). Thank you.

Comment: I was almost there when you messaged  :-D

Comment: If you look at the input form of `vor`, you can notice that this is a `MeshRegion` (so a list of coordinates and a list of `Polygon`). So you can assign a value to a case and will do follow the corresponding elements (If you want to keep the same index number).

Comment: @Jason B: Great ... great ... great ... it works perfect. Very last question and then I stop: how is the corresponding code when I want to select cells with a certain number of vortices and delete them?

Comment: I gotta run, but basically you need to be able to formulate a `True`/`False` test to run on the individual `Polygon` objects.  Try the function on, say, `MeshPrimitives[vor, 2][[1]]` to see if it works, then use the `Select` trick above.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe do something like this:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; pts = RandomReal[4, {20, 2}]] (* for reproducibility *)
vor = VoronoiMesh[pts, {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}];

plist = MapIndexed[{Text[#2[[1]], RegionCentroid[#1]], FaceForm[], 
                    EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Red]], #} &, MeshPrimitives[vor, 2]];

{Graphics[plist, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}], 
 Graphics[Select[plist,
          (ArcLength[RegionBoundary[Last[#]]] < 4 && Area[Last[#]] < 0.8) &],
          PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: just feels like its missing]

where `ArcLength[RegionBoundary[(* polygon *)]]` directly computes the perimeter.

Comment: Another nice solution ... thanks a lot J.M.

Answer (score 7):

I'll do something like this to build a new `MeshRegion` with only the smallest cells:

```
SeedRandom[0]
pts = RandomReal[4, {20, 2}];
vor = VoronoiMesh[pts, {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}]

vor2 = MeshRegion[
  MeshCoordinates[vor],
  With[{a = PropertyValue[{vor, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]}, 
   With[{m = Mean[a]}, Pick[MeshCells[vor, 2], UnitStep[a - m], 0]]]
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

You can also define a function to filter a mesh like this

```
Clear[filterVoronoiMesh]
filterVoronoiMesh[mesh_MeshRegion, at : _ : Automatic, 
  pt : _ : Automatic, np : _ : _] :=
 With[{
   a = PropertyValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellMeasure],
   p = RegionMeasure@*RegionBoundary /@ MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2],
   n = Length @@@ MeshCells[mesh, 2]
   },
  With[{
    aq = at /. Automatic -> LessEqualThan@Mean[a],
    pq = pt /. Automatic -> LessEqualThan@Mean[p],
    nq = MatchQ[np]
    },
   MeshRegion[
    MeshCoordinates[mesh],
    Pick[MeshCells[mesh, 2], 
     Boole[aq /@ a] + Boole[pq /@ p] + Boole[nq /@ n], 3]]
   ]]
```

The arguments are:

- the mesh to be filtered
- a *predicate* to select cells by the area (for example `LessEqualThan[10]`; if `Automatic` or missing use `LessEqualThan` the mean area value)
- a *predicate* to select cells by perimeter (for example `GreaterThan[5]`; if `Automatic` or missing use `LessEqualThan` the mean perimeter value)
- a *pattern* for the number of vertices (if missing any number pass the filter)

For example:

```
SeedRandom[0]
pts = RandomReal[4, {40, 2}];
vor = VoronoiMesh[pts, {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}]
filterVoronoiMesh[vor]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or

```
filterVoronoiMesh[vor, Automatic, Automatic, 4 | 6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This ist absolutely more than great ... I can only vote for one :-(