# How to get size of each polygon of a Voronoi diagram using Shoelace formula?

Tags: computational-geometry, polygons

The following code gets all vertices of all polygons (mesh cells) of `VoronoiMesh[pts]`:

```
SeedRandom[3]; 
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {25, 2}];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts];
vertices = MeshCoordinates[mesh];
Show[mesh, Graphics[{Black, Point[pts], Red, Point[vertices]}]]
```

This outputs:

[image: Voronoi]

#### My question

How can I get a list of vertices for each polygon and compute the area of each polygon using the [Shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula)?

The output should be similar to:

[image: Output]

So, by clicking on the polygon number, it should show its vertices and its size.

I found this tool-tip image in [Finding the perimeter, area and number of sides of a Voronoi cell](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20646)

Comment: Do you need to use the shoelace formula, or will the built in function `Area` suffice?

Comment: Yes. I need to use the `shoelace formula`, **not** `built-in function`.

Comment: See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22587) for an implementation of the shoelace formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
polygons = Join @@ MeshCells[mesh, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[All, 1]];
polygondata = With[{x = MeshCoordinates[mesh]}, Map[
    p \[Function] Partition[x[[p]], 2, 1, 1],
    polygons
    ]];
areas = 0.5 Total[Map[Det, polygondata, {2}], {2}];
circumferences = Total[Map[Norm, Differences /@ polygondata, {2}], {2}];
```

For the tooltipping, you can also use the option `MeshCellLabel` of `MeshRegion`, but that's are a bit unwieldy:

```
MeshRegion[mesh, MeshCellLabel -> Map[
   i \[Function] ({2, i} -> Tooltip[
       i,
       Grid[{
         {"Vertices", polygons[[i]]},
         {"Vertex Coordinates", polygondata[[i, All, 1]]},
         {"Area", areas[[i]]},
         {"Perimeter", circumferences[[i]]}
         },
        Alignment -> {Left, Top}
        ]
       ]
     ),
   Range[MeshCellCount[mesh, 2]]
   ]
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and your edit. That is helpful for getting the polygons' sizes of each polygon. If I want to show the vertices values of each polygon also. How can I do that?? Any suggestions??

Comment: Have a look at the last edit.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I am really sorry for disturbance. But, I think the **vertices** in the code, gives the order of the vertices of each polygon, **_not_** the **values of the vertices' points**.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Yes. It is exactly what I want to get. Thanks so much for your help. I really appreciate that.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Use `MeshPrimitives` like this:

```
Show[Graphics[{FaceForm@RGBColor[
    0.666, 0.776, 0.952], 
   Table[Tooltip[p, 
     Grid@{{"Perimeter", Perimeter@p}, {"Area", Area@p}, {"Edges", 
        Length @@ p}}], {p, MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2]}]}], 
 Graphics[{Black, Point[pts], Red, Point[vertices]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. But, if I want the vertices of each polygon to be shown also with area,edges and Perimeter. How to do that??

Comment: How are you ordering them?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and your reply. What did you mean by _them_ ? Did you mean the vertices?? If you mean the vertices, I don't order them. the code get all vertices of all voronoi polygons. I want to get the vertices of each polygon, separately. So, by clicking on each polygon; I can get its vertices.

Comment: Note that `PropertyValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]` is a faster way to get all of the areas. However I don't think the other properties can be computed in this way.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an efficient way to implement the shoelace formula, assuming no self intersections:

```
ShoelaceArea[Polygon[pts_?MatrixQ]] := 
  0.5 * #1.(RotateLeft[#2] - RotateRight[#2])& @@ Transpose[pts]
```

A comparison:

```
shoeareas = ShoelaceArea /@ MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
>  {0.000233, Null}
> ```

```
areas = PropertyValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
>  {0.000013, Null}
> ```

```
Max[Abs[shoeareas - areas]]
```

> ```
> 3.33067*10^-16
> ```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.