# Speed-up calculation of Area of Polygons

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, regions, polygons

I have a complicated polygon in the 2d plane, that is an `RegionIntersection` of `RegionUnion` of triangles.

Finally, I want to calculate it's Area. Unfortunatly, the `Area` is really slow. I am not sure why, but presumably because it calculates the result analytically.

I have an example that represents the shapes I am dealing with:

```
TotalTime = 0;
For[cc = 1, cc <= 50, cc++,
  (* Reconstructing roughly the shapes I am using *)
  BoundIntersect = RegionIntersection[
    RegionDifference[Triangle[RandomReal[{-0.2, 0.2}, {3, 2}]], 
     Polygon[RandomReal[{-0.2, 0.2}, {3, 2}]]], 
    RegionUnion[Triangle[RandomReal[{-0.2, 0.2}, {3, 2}]], 
     Triangle[RandomReal[{-0.2, 0.2}, {3, 2}]], 
     Triangle[RandomReal[{-0.2, 0.2}, {3, 2}]], 
     Triangle[RandomReal[{-0.2, 0.2}, {3, 2}]], 
     Triangle[RandomReal[{-0.2, 0.2}, {3, 2}]]]];

  CurrentTime = AbsoluteTime[];
  BoundaryIntersectRatio = Area[BoundIntersect];
  TotalTime += (AbsoluteTime[] - CurrentTime);
  ];
Print["Total Time: " <> ToString[TotalTime] <> " sec."];
```

Can you speed it up? In particular, error-ratios in the order of $10^{-4}$ are tolerable.

---

**Update (25.12.2019)**:

A fair comparison (100 iterations with same polygons for each method):

1. Henrik Schumacher's method using undocumented Graphics`PolygonUtils function: **0.75005 sec.**
2. Alx's suggestion using `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion:` **5.03149 sec.**
3. My original method: **24.50163 sec.**

Result: Speedup of >factor 30! And learned about undocumented function that i can use all over my code. Fantastic, thank you!

Comment: Maybe some speed-up can be obtained with `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`: `Area@RegionIntersection[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@RegionDifference[...],BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@RegionUnion[...]]`.

Comment: You can try one of the implemenations of the shoelace formula: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/207903/280

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These undocumented functions do the job almost two orders of magnitude faster:

```
BoundIntersect = Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonIntersection[
    Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonComplement @@ (Polygon /@ 
       RandomReal[{-0.2, 0.2}, {2, 3, 2}]),
    Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonCombine[
     Polygon /@ RandomReal[{-0.2, 0.2}, {5, 3, 2}]]
    ];
Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonArea[BoundIntersect]
```

Comment: `Area[BoundIntersect]` returns different result than ``Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonArea[BoundIntersect]``. Why?

Comment: Good point. I also observed this. Probably some sign errors. But `Area[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@BoundIntersect]` returns the same result as ``Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonArea[BoundIntersect]``, so I am quite confident that this result is true. Of course, this requires some further testing...

Comment: Thanks this is great! How do you find about undocumented functions? And how do you get more infos about this specific one?

Comment: Well, they are undocumented, so you hardly can find out. What I did to find it: You can search all _Mathematica_ contexts for a symbol that has `Polygon` in its name by evaluating ``?*`Polygon*``. Then I saw that the context ``Graphics`PolygonUtils`` might contain quite useful functions (see ``?Graphics`PolygonUtils`*``) The rest is just trying out different ways to call the functions in order to figure out the correct syntax. This works more often than one might expected.

Comment: Those undocumented are usually often backends to the more fleshed-out built-in functions. Often, they lack all the fancy argument processing capabilities, but this leads not seldomly to higher performance. IHowever, IIRC, the functions from the context ``Graphics`PolygonUtils`` predate all the `Region`-related functions.