# How to get the overlap's percentage that occurs between 2 circles or among more than 2 circles?

Tags: computational-geometry

The following code draws the following circles;

```
pts={{0.02,0.44},{0.08,0.58},{0.22,0.57},{0.3,0.9},{0.39,0.24},{0.44,0.79}, 
{0.65,0.19},{0.82,0.93},{0.93,0.7},{0.95,0.11}}
r = 0.2; 
Show[Graphics[{Blue, Circle[#, r] & /@ pts, Black, Point[pts], 
FaceForm[Opacity[.5,LightBlue]],EdgeForm[{Thick,Darker@Blue}],disks}]]
```

The output would be as the following image;

[image]

**My question is:**

How can I **detect** the **overlap** that occurs either between **2 circles** or **among more than 2 circles**? and How to get the **percentage of this overlap**?

The output should be similar like that:
[image]

So, by clicking on the overlap occurred between any 2 circles or among more than 2 circles, it should show:

- the **number** of the **overlapped circles**.
- the **percentage** of **this overlap**.
- the **ids** of the overlapped circles, e.g overlap occurred between circle 1 
  and circle 2, then **ids=1,2**.

I found this tool-tip image in [Finding the perimeter, area and number of sides of a Voronoi cell](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20646)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`RegionIntersection`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html) and [`RegionMeasure`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMeasure.html) from the [Region Properties and Measures](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GeometricPropertiesAndMeasures.html) guide to identify overlapping members. Then [`BooleanRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanRegion.html) and [`BooleanCountingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanCountingFunction.html) from the [Boolean Computation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/BooleanComputation.html) guide consolidate overlapping regions to calculate area.

From the plot there will be a few circles with disjoint regions but this should not be an issue.

```
Graphics[{Blue, Circle[#, r] & /@ pts, Black, Point[pts]},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> None]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

For each circle's disk all intersecting disk can be obtained by non-zero `RegionMeasure` from `RegionIntersection` of it and the other circle's disks.

```
overlaps = Association@MapIndexed[
   Function[{v, i},
    v -> Select[
       RegionMeasure[RegionIntersection[ Disk[v, r], Disk[#, r]], 2] > 0 &]@Drop[pts, i]
    ],
   pts
   ]
```

> ```
> <|
>   {0.02,0.44}->{{0.08,0.58},{0.22,0.57}},
>   {0.08,0.58}->{{0.02,0.44},{0.22,0.57},{0.3,0.9}},
>   {0.22,0.57}->{{0.02,0.44},{0.08,0.58},{0.3,0.9},{0.39,0.24},{0.44,0.79}},
>   {0.3,0.9}->{{0.08,0.58},{0.22,0.57},{0.44,0.79}},
>   {0.39,0.24}->{{0.22,0.57},{0.65,0.19}},
>   {0.44,0.79}->{{0.22,0.57},{0.3,0.9}},
>   {0.65,0.19}->{{0.39,0.24},{0.95,0.11}},
>   {0.82,0.93}->{{0.93,0.7}},
>   {0.93,0.7}->{{0.82,0.93}},
>   {0.95,0.11}->{{0.65,0.19}}
> |>
> ```

The keys are the primary circle and the values its intersecting circles.  `BooleanRegion` with a `BooleanCountingFunction` for 2 or more matches produces the consolidated overlapping region (even if the region is disjoint).  A [`RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html) of the region with the circles overlaid and the overlap percentage of the [`RegionUnion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionUnion.html) area of the participating circle disks is below.

```
KeyValueMap[
   Function[{k, v},
    With[{reg = 
       Region@BooleanRegion[
         BooleanCountingFunction[{2, 1 + Length@v}, 1 + Length@v], 
         Map[Disk[#, r] &, Append[v, k]]]},
     Show[{
       RegionPlot[reg,
        PlotStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[None], LightOrange],
        PlotRange -> {{-.2, 1.2}, {-.2, 1.2}}],
       Graphics[{
         {Blue, Circle[k, r], Point[k]},
         {Gray, Circle[#, r] & /@ v, Point[v]}}
        ]
       },
      Frame -> True,
      FrameTicks -> None,
      PlotLabel -> StringTemplate["Disk at (x = `1`, y = `2`)"] @@ k,
      FrameLabel -> {
        StringTemplate["Overlap (%): ``"][
         100 RegionMeasure[reg, 
            2]/(Area@*RegionUnion@Map[Disk[#, r] &, Append[v, k]])], 
        None}
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]@overlaps // Multicolumn[#, Appearance -> "Horizontal"] &
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much. It was really helpful.