# How to calculate border length between adjacent Voronoi regions?

Tags: mesh, computational-geometry

I have a set of Voronoi cells that I partition into some defined regions. I would like to then calculate the length of the "borders" between these adjacent regions, using the edges of the underlying Voronoi cells that constitute each region.

Suppose I have points `Ps`:

```
Ps = {{-0.025, -0.34},
{0.29, -0.11}, {0.31, 0.83}, {-0.76, 0.76}, {0.73, 0.13}, {-0.36, 0.13}, {-0.47, 0.84}, {-0.73, 0.10}, {-0.91, -0.65}, {0.73, -0.27}, {0.98, 0.71}, {-0.37, 0.25}, {-0.53, -0.08}, {-0.49, 0.06}, {-0.52, 0.34}};
```

Then I group them into 4 regions:

```
R1 = {2, 13, 6, 9};
R2 = {10, 4, 11, 5, 3};
R3 = {14, 12, 15};
R4 = {1, 7, 8};
```

We visualize the Voronoi Mesh `Vm` with these 4 regions:

```
Vm = VoronoiMesh[Ps, {-1, 1}, MeshCellLabel -> {2 -> "Index"},
  MeshCellStyle -> {{2, R1} -> LightOrange, {2, R2} -> 
     LightBlue, {2, R3} -> LightYellow, {2, R4} -> LightPink}]
```

[image]

How could I compute the perimeter length of each "border"?

For instance, what's the perimeter length of the Organge-Yellow border? (and so on, for all region borders).

[image]

I know we can compute individual Mesh-cell perimeters (e.g. [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20646/finding-the-perimeter-area-and-number-of-sides-of-a-voronoi-cell)), but how could we compute "border" perimeters between two arbitrary regions of the mesh?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to compute pairwise "border lengths", for instance:

`BorderLength[R1,R2] = some perimeter length`

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**

Construct a `MeshRegion` for each collection of faces `R1` thru `R4`:

```
pieces = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[Vm], MeshCells[Vm, {2, #}]] & /@ {R1, R2, R3, R4};
```

Find the `RegionIntersection` for each  pair of regions in `pieces` and collect the pairs with non-empty intersection in an `Association` using `"Ri-Rj"` as the key for the pair `{Ri, Rj}`:

```
borderAssoc = Association[DeleteCases[(StringRiffle["R" <> ToString@# & /@ #, "-"] -> 
        RegionIntersection @@ (pieces[[#]] & /@ #)) & /@ 
     Subsets[Range@Length@pieces, {2}], Rule[_, _EmptyRegion]]];
```

Line primitives for each border:

```
MeshPrimitives[#, 1] & /@ borderAssoc // Short[#, 3] &
```

> <|R1 - R2 -> {Line[{{-0.874688, -0.261875}, {-0.91, -0.2534}}], 
>      Line[{{-0.619773, 0.0213636}, {-0.874688, -<< 9 >>}}], 
>      Line[<< 1 >>], 
>      Line[{{-0.501794, 0.200344}, {-0.591545, 0.190727}}]}, << 4 >>|>

Border lengths can be obtained mapping `RegionMeasure` on `borderAssoc`:

```
 RegionMeasure /@ borderAssoc
```

> <|R1 - R2 -> 0.679339, R1 - R3 -> 0.868023, R2 - R3 -> 1.48467, 
>    R2 - R4 -> 0.0918997, R3 - R4 -> 1.65446|>

Construct a legend combining region colors in `Vm` with colors of your choice for border lines:

```
colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@Keys[borderAssoc]];

legend = Column[{SwatchLegend[{LightOrange, LightBlue, LightYellow,  LightPink}, 
     Row /@ Thread[ {"R" <> ToString@# <> " = " & /@ Range[4], {R1, R2, R3, R4}}], 
     LegendMarkerSize -> {20, 20}, LegendLabel -> "regions"], 
    LineLegend[colors, Row[#, " : "] & /@ 
      List @@@ Normal[RegionMeasure /@ borderAssoc], 
     LegendLabel -> "border lengths"]}];
```

Show `Vm` with the border lines and the legend:

```
Legended[Show[Vm, 
  Graphics@ {AbsoluteThickness[3], 
    Thread[{colors, Values[MeshPrimitives[#, 1] & /@ borderAssoc]}]}],
  Placed[legend, Right]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
pieces = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[Vm], MeshCells[Vm, {2, #}]] & /@ {R1, R2, R3, R4};

borders = DeleteCases[RegionIntersection @@@ Subsets[pieces, {2}], _EmptyRegion];

Show[Vm, Graphics @ {AbsoluteThickness[3], RandomColor[], #} & /@ 
   (MeshPrimitives[#, 1] & /@  borders)]
```

[image]

```
lengths = RegionMeasure[RegionUnion @@ #] & /@ borders
```

> {0.679339, 0.868023, 1.48467, 0.0918997, 1.65446}

Comment: This is great! But, how do we know which length corresponds to which border? By inspection, I see that the shortest length should be the pink-ish line between Region2-Region4. But, how could I retrieve this info from `lengths` or otherwise? Thanks!

Comment: @TumbiSapichu, please see the update.

Comment: That's definitely it! Would you mind commenting on the general approach? I can read the code/functions but I'd like to know a bit more about the logic behind; particularly interested in the logic behind `borderAssoc`. Thanks!

Comment: @TumbiSapichu, added a few notes.